# Abrir video youtube fullscreen

Tags: android

Estou usando o código abaixo para abrir um vídeo do youtube, porém gostaria que o mesmo abrisse já em tela cheia.

```
String id = "Zh-2d_AqiQQ";
Intent it_video_intro = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:" + id));
Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + id));
try {
  startActivity(it_video_intro);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
  startActivity(webIntent);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108441/play-youtube-video-in-full-screen-mode-in-my-android-app

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064244/how-to-force-a-video-to-play-in-fullscreen-in-youtube-player